# Go to high school or go to high schools?

Tags: articles, phrasal-verbs, indefinite-article

You usually say "Tom goes to high school", and you don't say "Tom goes to a high school" when you want to mean Tom is a student there, do you?

How about when you want to mention more than one high school?

When Tom and Becky are not from the same school, which sentence would be more appropriate?

A-1) Tom and Becky go to high school.
A-2) Tom and Becky go to high schools.

How about when there is an adjective?

B-1) Tom and Becky go to different high school.
B-2) Tom and Becky go to different high schools.

I'd like to know whether "to go to school" is always singular or it can be plural.  Thank you.

Comment: _School_ can have the sense of _full-time education_ as well as referring to an individual school. _Tom and Becky go to high school_ can mean that they are both of an age to be in secondary education, without necessarily implying anything about _which_ school(s) they attend.

Answer (score 1):

For A,

> Tom and Becky go to high school

is the best answer, as it shows that both Tom and Becky go to high school, but its unclear if they go to different schools.

For B,

> Tom and Becky go to different high schools

is the correct option as it is grammatically correct, as you are describing how two people go to **two** different high schools.

> I'd like to know whether "to go to school" is always singular or it can be plural

"go to school" can be used in "They go to school" and also "I go to school", and "We go to school", so its interchangeably used between plural and singular.